# apt-get software-properties-common installs cron improperly

Tags: apt, dpkg, cron

Problem:
"apt-get install software-properties-common" installs cron improperly.
During the installation, cron package seems to be not installed.
However, after the installation, dpkg prints the state of the cron as unknown and not-installed.
Moreover, installing other packages that requires cron as its dependencies (e.g. logrotate) skips the installation of cron. Explicit installation of cron is required to solve this problem.

Question
: Is this a issue of software-properties-common package?

Environment:

- Windows 10 Machine
- Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image

Commands

1. dpkg -l cron

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching cron
```

2. apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common [TL;DR]

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates dbus dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dirmngr distro-info-data dmsetup file
  gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnupg
  gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gsettings-desktop-schemas iso-codes
  krb5-locales libapparmor1 libappstream4 libargon2-1 libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libbrotli1 libcap2 libcap2-bin
  libcryptsetup12 libdbus-1-3 libdconf1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libelf1 libexpat1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libicu66 libip4tc2 libjson-c4 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkmod2 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblmdb0 libmagic-mgc
  libmagic1 libmpdec2 libnpth0 libnss-systemd libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpam-cap libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libproxy1v5 libpsl5 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libreadline8
  libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsoup2.4-1 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstemmer0d
  libwind0-heimdal libxml2 libyaml-0-2 lsb-release mime-support networkd-dispatcher openssl packagekit
  packagekit-tools pinentry-curses policykit-1 publicsuffix python-apt-common python3 python3-apt python3-certifi
  python3-chardet python3-dbus python3-distro-info python3-gi python3-idna python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources
  python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-six python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 python3.8
  python3.8-minimal readline-common shared-mime-info systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd ucf unattended-upgrades
  xdg-user-dirs xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  pinentry-gnome3 tor parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon isoquery krb5-doc krb5-user gstreamer1.0-tools
  libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp
  libsasl2-modules-sql iw | wireless-tools appstream pinentry-doc python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3-apt-dbg
  python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg python3-setuptools python3-cryptography python3-openssl
  python3-socks python3.8-venv python3.8-doc binutils binfmt-support readline-doc systemd-container bsd-mailx
  default-mta | mail-transport-agent needrestart powermgmt-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates dbus dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dirmngr distro-info-data dmsetup file
  gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnupg
  gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gsettings-desktop-schemas iso-codes
  krb5-locales libapparmor1 libappstream4 libargon2-1 libasn1-8-heimdal libassuan0 libbrotli1 libcap2 libcap2-bin
  libcryptsetup12 libdbus-1-3 libdconf1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libelf1 libexpat1 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal
  libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libicu66 libip4tc2 libjson-c4 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkmod2 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblmdb0 libmagic-mgc
  libmagic1 libmpdec2 libnpth0 libnss-systemd libpackagekit-glib2-18 libpam-cap libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libproxy1v5 libpsl5 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libreadline8
  libroken18-heimdal libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsoup2.4-1 libsqlite3-0 libssl1.1 libstemmer0d
  libwind0-heimdal libxml2 libyaml-0-2 lsb-release mime-support networkd-dispatcher openssl packagekit
  packagekit-tools pinentry-curses policykit-1 publicsuffix python-apt-common python3 python3-apt python3-certifi
  python3-chardet python3-dbus python3-distro-info python3-gi python3-idna python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources
  python3-requests python3-requests-unixsocket python3-six python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 python3.8
  python3.8-minimal readline-common shared-mime-info software-properties-common systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  ucf unattended-upgrades xdg-user-dirs xz-utils
0 upgraded, 128 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

3-1. dpkg -l

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version                    Architecture Description
+++-=============================-==========================-============-==============================================
=================================
ii  adduser                       3.118ubuntu2               all          add and remove users and groups
ii  apt                           2.0.4                      amd64        commandline package manager
ii  base-files                    11ubuntu5.3                amd64        Debian base system miscellaneous files
ii  base-passwd                   3.5.47                     amd64        Debian base system master password and group f
iles
ii  bash                          5.0-6ubuntu1.1             amd64        GNU Bourne Again SHell
ii  bsdutils                      1:2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1        amd64        basic utilities from 4.4BSD-Lite
ii  bzip2                         1.0.8-2                    amd64        high-quality block-sorting file compressor - u
tilities
ii  ca-certificates               20210119~20.04.1           all          Common CA certificates
ii  coreutils                     8.30-3ubuntu2              amd64        GNU core utilities
ii  dash                          0.5.10.2-6                 amd64        POSIX-compliant shell
```

3-2. dpkg -l cron

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  cron           <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

4. apt-get update && apt-get install cron

```
Suggested packages:
  anacron logrotate checksecurity default-mta | mail-transport-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cron
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

5. dpkg -l cron

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version           Architecture Description
+++-==============-=================-============-=================================
ii  cron           3.0pl1-136ubuntu1 amd64        process scheduling daemon
```

Tried solutions:
"dpkg --forget-old-unavail", "dpkg --clear-avail", "apt-get autoremove", "apt-get upgrade" did not help.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the `cron` package is a dependency of the `software-properties-common` package?

Comment: @user535733 I've tried to start the cron service just after the installation of logrotate package (which installs cron as its dependency in normal case). However, `service cron start` said no such service available. Because this problem was occurred inside the docker with only a few packages, each package was tested and software-properties-common was found as a responsible one.

Comment: How was the `software-properties-common` package found as responsible? Your output does not show `logrotate` to be a dependency of `software-properties-common`  (correct -- it's not). Missing logrotate suggests that you did not install `ubuntu-standard`, so other expected utilities may be missing.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I meant `software-properties-common` was the cause of this problem, not the dependency of `logrotate`. What I did was just start the Ubuntu Docker image, install `locales`, `tzdata`, `software-properties-common`, and install some other packages. Before installing `software-properties-common`, `apt-get install logrotate` tries to install `cron libpopt0`. However, after the installation of `software-properties-common`, `apt-get install logrotate` just tries to install `libpopt0`.

Comment: I've thought this was a problem of `software-properties-common` because the result of `dpkg -l cron` has changed after its installation. However, testing the same process again for `anacron`, which also requires `cron` as its dependency, did not make any problem. This may be the problem of `logrotate`. I'm sorry for bothering and thank you for your insight @user535733.

Comment: That seems like normal behavior in many circumstances. "Install package-A" followed by "Remove package-A" does not always restore the original state. Some dependencies will be removed, some won't. Depends upon how many layers of dependencies got installed. You must compare the list of installs and removals carefully. "apt autoremove" can also help to restore the initial state.